# x:Bind type can't be found

Tags: linq, xaml, uwp, collectionviewsource, xbind

I'm attempting to use a `CollectionViewSource` in my XAML in order to have a grouped `ListView`.

The CSV:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyViewSource"
                      IsSourceGrouped="True"
                      Source="{Binding MyItems, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And my `DataTemplate` which I provide to the `ItemTemplate` property on my `GridView` which I'm using for the "zoomed out" view:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="JumpTemplate"
              x:DataType="data:ICollectionViewGroup">
    <TextBlock FontSize="32"
               FontWeight="SemiLight"                       
               Text="{x:Bind ((linq:IGrouping)Group).Key}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) this should cast the item to an `IGrouping` object, which then gives me access to the `Key` property. However, I keep getting an error

> Invalid binding path '((linq:IGrouping)Group).Key' : Type 'linq:IGrouping' can't be found.

I've very clearly defined it:

```
xmlns:data="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Data"
xmlns:linq="using:System.Linq"
```

I know it's not a typo or something because `Go to definition` on the `linq:IGrouping` works just fine.

Are there certain types which aren't allowed to be used or something?

I'm on Windows 10 build 16257.1, using VS 2017 and SDK Preview 16257.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct:

> Type 'linq:IGrouping' can't be found.

There is no `IGrouping` type in LINQ, there is however a `IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement>` type which is not the same thing. Such a cast will fail in C# also.

`XAML` doesn't allow to specify generic type parameters so I think you are stuck with a normal binding: `Text="{Binding Key}"`